# How to open document directory like whatsapp while sending a document... not an Image

Tags: android

I just wanted to open document directory with listing of all the documents only not images. I am using below code

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// The MIME data type filter
intent.setType("application/*");
// Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

but it's working in a different way on other devices

Comment: Have u figured out the way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
            String mimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), (extension.isEmpty() || mimeType == null) ? "text/*" : mimeType);
            // custom message for the intent
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Application:"));
```

Comment: what is file here  Uri.fromFile(**file**).toString()

Comment: Full path of file

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 File file = new File(name);
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 String type = "application/msword/pdf/vnd.ms-powerpoint/vnd.ms-excel";
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this dude.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("application/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select files"), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp displays his own document picker screen first, and if you click "**Browse other docs...**" It shows system UI  document picker with below intent:

Intent reference: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

```
// Change according to your requirement
val mimeTypes = arrayOf(
    "image/jpeg", // jpeg or jpg
    "image/png", // png
    "application/pdf", // pdf
    "application/msword", // doc
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // docx
    "application/vnd.ms-excel", // xls
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // xlsx
    "video/mp4", // mp4
    "audio/mpeg", // mp3
)

private val filePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), ::onFilePickerResult
)

private fun startFilePicker() {
    val pickerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
    pickerIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    pickerIntent.type = "*/*"
    pickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
    pickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    filePickerLauncher.launch(pickerIntent)
}

private fun onFilePickerResult(result: ActivityResult) {
    if (result.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return
    }

    val multipleUriData = result.data?.clipData
    val singleUri = result.data?.data

    when {
        multipleUriData != null -> {
            for (i in 0 until multipleUriData.itemCount) {
                val uri = multipleUriData.getItemAt(i).uri
                //TODO: validateAndSendFile(uri)
            }
        }
        singleUri != null -> {
            //TODO: validateAndSendFile(singleUri)
        }
        else -> return
    }
}
```